# Class/Functional component, methods within

Tags: javascript, reactjs, class, react-functional-component

I'm quite new to ReactJs and I'm trying to understand a little more detail.

In a Class component, these are the two ways that I know I can declare a handler method to change the state

```
 classChangeState=()=>{
         this.setState({
             Person:[
                 {firstName:"test", secondName:55}
             ]
         })
     }

classChangeState2(){
    console.log("Inside Change state click")
    this.setState({
         Person:[
             {firstName:"test", secondName:55}
         ]
     })enter code here
 //classChangeState2 require me to bind "this" inside render method
```

In functional component the below two ways I can do it

```
    function changeStateClick(){
            changeState({
             Person:[
                {firstName: "Just aasefaesfstring property", secondName: 32}
            ]
        })
        }

    const changeStateClick2 =()=> changeState({
             Person:[
                {firstName: "Just a[[[string property", secondName: 32}
            ]
        })
```

I have a few questions 
1) how does React know that classChangeState2 is a method without the "function"?

2) I know that I can pass in a newName as parameters in all of the above methods above but I must bind "THIS" in the render for all methods. For e.g
methodName.bind(this,"newNamehere")

why is this? Even for the functional component where initially I did not need to bind when I want to add "newName" as a parameter, I must now bind. Can someone explain, please?

```
classChangeState=(newName)=>{
         this.setState({
             Person:[
                 {firstName:newName, secondName:55}
             ]
         })
     }
```

Comment: You really want to take some time and run through https://reactjs.org/tutorial/tutorial.html - it's well written, it _actually_ covers all the basics, and you're infinitely better at React afterwards. Open a code editor, actually run the examples, learn React. It's time well spent.

Comment: Yup i did go through that, but i feel that it's not detailed enough in some parts where i still get lost , i get the overall flow of how props and component works but i feel that sometimes i think too much and it over complicate my brain. 
i ran through the documentation too with regards to my question but i still have holes inbetween. 
Anyway
Thanks!

Comment: The other one is that you also want a good tutorial on modern JS (not any of the million ones that still teach 1998 nonsense JS), to explain how modern constructs like classes, arrow functions, etc. work, and when you would use them, and why (for example: if you don't need to preserve what `this` means, there is literally no benefit to using an arrow function).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I have a few questions 1) how does React know that classChangeState2
>   is a method without the "function"?

It's not related to *React*, but ES6. Classes are syntactical sugar and they are just special functions. And what you're seeing as a method is just a short hand for a function assigned to a method's name. So when you write this:

```
   class fooClass {
    bar(...) {} 
   }
```

`fooClass` is actually a function and the methods inside that for e.g `bar` are written to `fooClass.prototype`. Also, you'd like to see,

> Starting with ECMAScript 2015, a shorter syntax for method
>   definitions on objects initializers is introduced. It is a shorthand
>   for a function assigned to the method's name.

```
 const obj = {
  foo() {
    return 'bar';
  }
};

console.log(obj.foo());
```

You can go through more on [MDN- Classes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes) and [function-definitions MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Method_definitions)

Coming to the second part of the question,

> 2) I know that I can pass in a newName as parameters in all of the
>   above methods above but I must bind "THIS" in the render for all
>   methods. For e.g methodName.bind(this,"newNamehere")

This syntax is **experimental class property** and you can use this instead of `bind`ing the method in the constructor. Note that this syntax may change.

Read More https://reactjs.org/docs/react-without-es6.html#autobinding

https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-transform-class-properties/

Comment: Thank you, i over think and didn't think of how a class works. I totally get it now!